# cant set width and height on div

Tags: html, css

I am doing a project where we are learning how to design the google homepage. My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HgpQW/ . I realize that my work is far from complete, but I am hoping somebody can just help me with one thing: why can't I expand the "SIGN IN" element? I have tried to do so with setting width and height in the css, but it has no effect.

```
<header> 
  <ul id="headerlist"> 
    <li>+You</li>
    <li>Gmail</li>
    <li id="grid">
    <li id="sign_in"> 
      <div id="sign_in">
        <span>SIGN IN</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

__

```
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li, li div {
  display:inline
}

#headerlist li {
  padding-right: 6px;
}

#sign_in {
  display:block;
  background-color: #DA4531;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

EDIT: the solution was inline-block on the #sign_in li

Comment: You linked to a blank jsfiddle, can you fix the link?

Comment: You can't link to jsfiddle from StackOverflow without putting in a code block here. That's why the fiddle is coming up blank. I've pasted in your css from the jsfiddle page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` elements normally have display:block; applied but you must have somehow changed this to `display:inline;`

If you didn't do this yourself, it might have been a boilerplate CSS that you used that caused this.

To be able to adjust the width, change the display to:

```
display:block;
```

or this will also work and may be preferable if you previously found a need to remove the default block display:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Another possibility could be that your div is contained within another div and that parents divs `overflow` is set to `hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Without a link to a specific fiddle, it's hard to answer your question specifically. Just from your description, I'm guessing it might need this css:

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Thanks. That did allow me to set the height & width. As I feared, though, that caused my list elements (of which the "SIGN IN" element is one) to no longer appear on the same line

Comment: Use inline-block instead